# Correct C header structure

Tags: c, module, header

What is the correct way to structure headers? There are some similar-ish questions but none give a good answer. Right now I'm using this:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILENAME
#define INCLUDE FILENAME

/* Includes */

/* Constants, enums */

/* Structure */

/* Globals */

/* Function prototypes */

#include "File.c"

#endif
```

I then #include the header from the program.

This has a a lot of problems with having to include things in the right order, and I am fairly sure this is the wrong structure.

Ideally it should work when building a single file AND building modules seperately.

A related question is: Should globals be implemented in the header, or defined as extern and implemented in the source file?

Comment: Why do you define the macro INCLUDE to be FILENAME? :)

Comment: Do you actually include source files inside header files, as shown in your example?  That is generally frowned upon, because it can lead to multiple definition issues.

Comment: Nobody & Nate hit the nail on the head.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `#define INCLUDE_FILENAME`?

Comment: @Bart and @ Nobody, sorry: yes it was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, a header file should not define any data or code. That means globals should only be *declared* in the header and then *defined* in the source file.

The purpose of a header file is to give hints to the compiler, not to contain the actual data and code.

Also, source files are not meant to be included at all, each source file is usually passed to a compiler directly.

Comment: to clarify for the OP which does seem to be a beginner: a variable is _declared_ in a header file using the `extern` keyword. it is _defined_ in the corresponding source file by repeating the same declaration but omitting the `extern` keyword. (although, the use of global variable is quite debatable)

Comment: To declare but not define a global variable, put the "extern" keyword in front of it.  That says to the compiler "there's a symbol of this type with this name in another compilation unit".  Or better yet, restrict direct access to a global to the compilation unit in which it is defined.  Use function  calls to access it from other units.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson: beat me to it by about 20 seconds.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson, In this case the globals are typically string tables or similar. I have been programming long enough to know when and when not to use globals, it is C and it's quirks that are new to me.

Comment: @Jerry:  This example program gives yields an "undefined reference to test" error when compiled with GCC.  `extern int test;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return test;
}` 

  Please provide an example of `extern type name` acting as a definition.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: That *should* be the case if you're compiling it as C++. In C, however, it's more complicated. The standard (§6.9.2/4) gives the example: `extern int i3 = 3; // definition, external linkage`. To ensure against it being taken as a definition, you not only need `extern`, but must also omit any initializer.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks!  If it's not too much to ask, what in the heck is the use case/rationale?  My first thought was that it could be used to define weak symbols (like a #pragma weak) in libraries (to be optionally overridden by the user) however that is not the behavior here.  It appears to behave exactly the same as a normal definition without the `extern`.  Bizarre.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: According to the C rationale: "Prior to C90, implementations varied widely with regard to forward referencing identifiers with internal linkage (see §6.2.2). The C89 committee invented the concept of tentative definition to handle this situation." IOW, probably no real use beyond compatibility with existing code (and possibly compilers).

Answer (score 1):

I for instance, don't like this approach, my solution is not portable, but I'm not planning to port it to any other platform.
I'm using the `#pragma once` IAR compiler extension, which causes the compiler to include this file only once, no matter how many times it's included.

Here's an example taken from Wikepdia, of how it's used:

```
#pragma once

struct foo 
{
    int member;
};
```

Instead of:

```
#ifndef GRANDFATHER_H
#define GRANDFATHER_H

struct foo
{
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDFATHER_H */
```

I think it's much more cleaner approach...

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), this directive is supported also in 
Clang,Comeau C/C++,Digital Mars C++,GCC,Intel C++ Compiler,Microsoft Visual Studio
So in practice It's quite portable... :)

Comment: Is the `#pragma once` in the second example a mistake or am I misunderstanding something about this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste, you should only make sure things are declared or forward-declared before they're used, which depends on your code.

And you don't normally include `#include` `.c` in headers.